# Will my data loss while converting dynamic disk to basic disk using minitool partition wizard?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I want to convert my harddrive from dynamic type to basic type using "Minitool Partition Wizard" to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Will converting process (from dynamic to basic) damage my data on harddrive?

Answer (score 3):

When performing any disc operations, enlarging or shrinking partitions, moving partitions, or in your case "convert my harddrive from dynamic type to basic type" there is always the possibility for data loss.

Data loss can happen at any time with no warning.

It is not a matter of if data loss can happen, but when it does happen you will have to restore from back up.

I suggest you choose a back up strategy and confirm you have a working copy of any data you value.

From the wiki page below,

> Backup and recovery is essential. Failure to have verified backup and
>   recovery procedures puts your data at risk of loss. Users often only
>   learn this lesson after critical information they require is
>   permanently lost. Attempting to recover from data loss can be both
>   time consuming and extremely difficult. So learn from others mistakes,
>   and ensure beforehand that you have a system in place that protects
>   your data and suits your needs.

See - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem for details

Comment: I can't remember how many times I've seen posts from people who've trashed their disks trying to do low-level operations -- or whose disks have simply "died" with no warning for no apparent reason! Make backups! That said, a dynamic-to-basic conversion is likely to be fairly simple and therefore relatively safe compared to, say, resizing a partition; but it really depends on the details of how the system is set up. Also, keep in mind that the Windows partitioning tools are unsafe with logical partitions, so don't use them after the conversion; use Linux or third-party tools.